# Import settings from Chrome to Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, browser

I try to change from Chrome to FF4. I have many passwords that I want to migrate to FF. I tried to export the passwords from Chrome with [Chromepass](http://www.nirsoft.net). Its ok. I got them in CSV.

Then I installed a Firefox extension so I have an export / import option in *Tools/Security*.

How can I import my passwords to FF4 from Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

My (workaround) suggestion would be to install [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) in Chrome and let it import your Chrome passwords. Then install the LastPass extension in Firefox and voila, your passwords are synced.

Comment: Its not a bad idea, but iam scared to upload all my username/password to Lastpass server.. any other idea?

Comment: @holian Wait, you're scared to upload them to an encrypted storage but keep a plain text readable CSV file on your computer? :) It's not that I would totally trust online companies either (see Sony, etc.) but if you keep a strong master password and your real passwords are not "password" or something like that, you're safe. The real benefit is that you can migrate your passwords more easily. And I honestly don't know any other method, sorry.

Comment: i think you know this proverb: "my house is my castle". But maybee you have right...

Answer (score 0):

That feature is pending for Firefox, they already implemented cookies, history and bookmarks migration in Firefox 11 but passwords, form data, and settings are still under development.

See here for details:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Features/Chrome_migration
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=589589